# HTML5 Canvas Graphics and Animation

Tags: ios, html, canvas

We are build a HTML 5 website. One feature is to use Canvas to resize images on Iphone/IPAD before uploading to our server.

On IPhone 4S and 5, when photos are taken in landscape mode with FRONT camera, the resizing works fine. When taken in portrait mode, the images are squashed by about 1/4. But when taken with rear camera, all images, both landscape and portrait, are squashed by about 7/8, leaving just a thin belt to view.

On IPAD and IPOD, it is the same for front and rear camera: landscape images are fine, but portrait images are squashed by 1/4.

We tried several different resizing algorithms, but ended up with the same results. Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Comment: The cameras return different resolution images. You'll need to apply different algo for both (you can target same resolution, just different scale). Hard to say what's going on otherwise.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem has been resolved   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554947/mobile-safari-renders-img-src-dataimage-jpegbase64-scaled-on-canvas/12615436#12615436