# Problems with iOS 6 Canvas iPhone Image Upload

Tags: image-processing, html5-canvas, image-uploading

i've got a problem by uploading an image into the HTML 5 Canvas Object.
When i was uploading the images with my computer it works fine and i have no problems. but when any image is uploaded from the iPhone-Camera, the origin height is getting distorted.

how can i fix this bug? 
does any one know, how to fix this, working together with [fabric.js](http://www.fabricjs.com) ? because i'm not drawing the images into the canvas 2d context but in the layers of the fabric.js. this is important to get the full interactivity with all items, drawn on canvas.

i hope anyone could help me.

thanks in advance

P.S

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this answer is related to yours but it might get you in the right direction:
[Mobile Safari renders <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64..."> scaled on Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554947/mobile-safari-renders-img-src-dataimage-jpegbase64-scaled-on-canvas/12615436#12615436)